# Convert Rectangle to circle

Tags: c, deep-learning, drawing, geometry, yolo

I'm trying to detect object using circle, I use the framework darknet based on yolo deep learning.
I have to change this function and I try to change this function from `draw_rectangle` to `draw_circle`,
How to do that?

```c
void draw_box(image a, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, float r, float g, float b) {
    //normalize_image(a);
    int i;
    if (x1 < 0) x1 = 0;
    if (x1 >= a.w) x1 = a.w - 1;
    if (x2 < 0) x2 = 0;
    if (x2 >= a.w) x2 = a.w - 1;

    if (y1 < 0) y1 = 0;
    if (y1 >= a.h) y1 = a.h - 1;
    if (y2 < 0) y2 = 0;
    if (y2 >= a.h) y2 = a.h - 1;

    for (i = x1; i <= x2; ++i) {
        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;

        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;

        a.data[i + y1*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
        a.data[i + y2*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
    }
    for(i = y1; i <= y2; ++i) {
        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 0*a.w*a.h] = r;

        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 1*a.w*a.h] = g;

        a.data[x1 + i*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
        a.data[x2 + i*a.w + 2*a.w*a.h] = b;
    }
}

void draw_box_width(image a, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int w, float r, float g, float b) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
        draw_box(a, x1+i, y1+i, x2-i, y2-i, r, g, b);
    }
}
```

So, the results show like that:
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyJeD.png

I want to change this to a circle

Comment: You could use [Bresenham’s circle drawing algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/) which is an efficient and trigonometry-free way to plot a circle.

Comment: but bresenhman's circle drawing algorithm uses in c other library than exist in the file image.c

Comment: It simply computes the locations of pixels to set, like your `draw_box()` function does. It needs no external resources, or math functions.

Comment: it needs graphics.h and dos.h headers

Comment: No, that's for their example. You plot pixels at the (x, y) coordinates generated in the loop, reflected to the other quadrants, in exactly the same way that you plot the sides of your box.

Comment: can you give me an exemple to do that? i think it was a bit difficult

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you: there are plenty of examples and descriptions of this well-known algorithm, and not enough time has gone by for you to have tried.

Comment: Yes , i know but i want to draw circle on image , please see again the code that i put in the post

Comment: You didn't write that function did you? This is a good learning opportunity for you.

Comment: Even the author himself Alexey told you to implement your own method haha https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2785. Try to solve the problem first, then we can see what have you tried

Comment: The problem is the input of image and the number of values of input for drawing circle that is not equivalent to the number of values for drawing box , did you unterstand this or no?

Comment: Okey , i will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of the Bresenham algorithm to plot an ellipsis on your `image` (adapted from https://gist.github.com/bert/1085538):

```c
void set_pixel(image a, int x, int y, float r, float g, float b) {
    if (x >= 0 && x < a.w && y >= 0 && y < a.h) {
        a.data[x + y * a.w + 0 * a.w * a.h] = r;
        a.data[x + y * a.w + 1 * a.w * a.h] = g;
        a.data[x + y * a.w + 2 * a.w * a.h] = b;
    }
}

void plot_ellipsis_rect(image a, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, float r, float g, float b) {
   int a = abs(x1 - x0), b = abs(y1 - y0), b1 = b & 1; /* values of diameter */
   long dx = 4 * (1 - a) * b * b, dy = 4 * (b1 + 1) * a * a; /* error increment */
   long err = dx + dy + b1 * a * a, e2; /* error of 1.step */

   y0 += (b + 1) / 2;
   y1 = y0 - b1;   /* starting pixel */
   a = 8 * a * a;
   b1 = 8 * b * b;
   do {
       set_pixel(a, x1, y0, r, g, b); /*   I. Quadrant */
       set_pixel(a, x0, y0, r, g, b); /*  II. Quadrant */
       set_pixel(a, x0, y1, r, g, b); /* III. Quadrant */
       set_pixel(a, x1, y1, r, g, b); /*  IV. Quadrant */
       e2 = 2 * err;
       if (e2 >= dx) {
          x0++;
          x1--;
          err += dx += b1;
       }
       if (e2 <= dy) {
          y0++;
          y1--;
          err += dy += a;
       }
   } while (x0 <= x1);
   while (y0 - y1 < b) {  /* too early stop of flat ellipses a=1 */
       set_pixel(a, x0 - 1, y0, r, g, b); /* -> finish tip of ellipse */
       set_pixel(a, x1 + 1, y0++, r, g, b); 
       set_pixel(a, x0 - 1, y1, r, g, b);
       set_pixel(a, x1 + 1, y1--, r, g, b); 
   }
}
```